# SPSS Output modify - deleting footnotes

Tags: syntax, output, spss

When generating tables in SPSS with the calculation of the mode it will show a footnote when multiple modes are present ("a. Multiple modes exist. The smallest value is shown").

There is a way to hide this footnote, but the hidden footnote will still take up an empty row in the output. For processing reasons I would like to delete the footnote entirely.

I have been trying to do this with the Output Modify command in the syntax, but can't get it to work. There are commands for selecting the footnotes:

/TABLECELLS
SELECT = ["expression", COUNT, MEAN, MEDIAN, RESIDUAL,
PERCENT, SIGNIFICANCE, POSITION(integer),
BODY, HEADERS, FOOTNOTES, TITLE, CAPTION, …]

And for deleting objects:

/DELETEOBJECT DELETE={NO**}
{YES }

But trying to combine these does not yield the wanted result. Is what I am trying to do possible? Or maybe a suggestion for another solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

try adding `"NOTESCAPTIONS = NO"` at the end of your OUTPUT MODIFY syntax.
that should remove all notes and captions in the output.
no need to use `"DELETEOBJECT"` subcommand.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried this and unfortunately an extra empty row still shows up in the exported output at the spot where the removed footnote was.

Comment: Ha! Why don't you try using SET FOOTNOTE=NO before the rest of your syntax? It should remove all the footnotes from your output (including tables). Let me know how it went.